# .NET 4.5 WCF Service Application in Solution breaks Web Site in same Solution

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with four projects:  Two class libraries, an nunit test project and a web site.

These four projects all play nicely with each other and the web site loads in the browser when starting the solution from VS 2012 as expected.

However, when I add a WCF Service Application only the page at the root of the site will load.  Any other pages that are in sub-folders will not load and report a 404.

If I remove the default WCF Service the pages in the website will load again, but as soon as I add a new WCF Service to the WCF Service Application the pages in sub-folders will no longer load.

Has anyone experienced this strange behaviour before?  If so, do you know the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not reproduce your issue to help. Here are the steps that I followed. Create a solution in VS 2012 and add a asp.net web site. Then add a WCF service application project to the same solution. Try creating a sub folder in the website and drop an aspx page. Now browse to the aspx page. Do you have a repro that you can upload somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @Praburaj.  It turned out this was a problem with IIS Express in VS 2012: It was referencing the wrong project and I was getting some strange behaviour.